# getting problem in implementing moowmd multiple editor on a single page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

want to use this editor : http://moowmd.awardspace.info/moowmd-tutorial.html

getting only textarea..not displaying button-bar & preview

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loaded()
{
var WConfig=[
{
    input: 'some-id',
    postfix: 'XXX'
}
```

];
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    window.MyWMD=new mooWMD.WMD(window.WConfig);
    window.MyWMD.start();
}
}

....
....

@Model.CommentText

Answer (score 0):

The MooWMD editor has several dependencies:

- MooTools library
- moowmd.js
- wmd.css
- images

Make sure that you have included all those dependencies to your project.

So here's a full working example (download the [`moowmd`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/files/mooWMD/moowmd.js.v1.1.tar.gz/download) package and place its contents into a `moowmd` folder to your site):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/moowmd/wmd.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style> 
    textarea {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .wmd-panel {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wmd-editor-uno" class="wmd-panel"> 
        <div id="wmd-button-bar-uno" class="wmd-button-bar"></div> 
        <textarea name="id-uno" id="id-uno"></textarea> 
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.3/mootools-yui-compressed.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/moowmd/moowmd.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var WConfig = [
        {
            input: 'id-uno',
            postfix: '-uno'
        }
    ];

    window.addEvent('domready', function () {
        window.MyWMD = new mooWMD.WMD(window.WConfig);
        window.MyWMD.start();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```